# Does React Router always rerender page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router and I have a component that uses `<Link>`. I am passing `<Link>` a function like so: `<Link to={mySpecialFunction(props)} />`.

`mySpecialFunction()` returns a string representation of the current page's path in certain cases. My question is this: does React Router refresh or reload the page if I am linking to the page that the user is currently on?

Everything is working fine, but there is some concern about unnecessary reloads from my team. I cannot see any activity in the Network tab, but I cannot find explicit confirmation in the React Router documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: React Router it's SPA routing so does not refresh your page, it uses History API underneath.

Comment: @Indgalante But is it still rerendering if the path is to the same page?

Comment: That's likely because you're changing the state every time the route changes.

Comment: Why are you worried about re-renders? Rendering in react is super cheap since the dom doesn't actually update unless something in render output changes

Comment: I agree, @azium. I just want to make sure I have all the facts correct when explaining to the rest of the team.

Comment: This is pretty easy to test no? Just click on the link and check if render is called again.

Comment: @azium When you put it like that, yeah, you're right.